# Connection between subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, maximal-subgroup

Let M be any maximal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is not a subgroup of $M$. So, $NM \leq G$. Does that necessarily mean $|NM|=|G|$? why yes or no?

My guessing is no for example if $G=Z_{12}$, $N=\langle2\rangle$,$M=\langle3\rangle$. Am I right?

Thanks

Edit: Im interested to this problem because I want to see if there is any case that $|NM|$ is not equal $|G|$ under stated conditions.

Comment: What if $N\leq M$?

Comment: Please share your own thoughts on this problem and provide context as to why your are interested in this. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Your edit is basically the tautology "I'm interested in this because I'm interested in this.". Provide proper context and share your own thoughts.

Comment: Hope now I justify your concern @Christoph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $N$ is normal, $MN$ is a subgroup with $M \subseteq MN \subseteq G$. Now use that $M$ is maximal and $N \not\subseteq M$ to infer that $G=MN$.

Comment: Thanks @Nicky Hekster. But my example doesn't apply here?

Comment: Since $2$ and $3$ are relativley prime, $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}=\langle 2,3\rangle$: Bézout's Theorem guarantees the existence of integers $k,l$ with $1=2k+3l$. So your example is not a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, $1 = 3 + (-2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Comment: No problem, hope you gained further insight into groups! And keep asking questions, also showing some efforts of your own of course.